# Looking for a .txt word frequency list to test a program

Tags: text-files, frequency, word-frequency

I'd like a file of the 200-1000 or so most frequently used words in the English language. I've been able to find ridiculous lists of 200,000 words or whatever, but nothing with a smaller set of the more frequently used words.

Preferably the words would be one per line but if it's not then I can format it.

THANKS!

Comment: Couldn't you just write a little program to pick out the top 200-1000 most frequent entries from one of those giant lists?

Comment: These must exist though... I'll keep looking around before I commit to a task like that.

Comment: @cksubs, it shouldn't be to hard, my answer shows what should(!) be a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the top 250 (you emphasized less is more) from McWafflestix's link, straight up, no extraneous spaces, etc, thanks to kill-rectangle in emacs.  I have to say, this is a pretty trivial and non-programming-related.

```
the
of
to
and
a
in
is
it
you
that
he
was
for
on
are
with
as
I
his
they
be
at
one
have
this
from
or
had
by
hot
but
some
what
there
we
can
out
other
were
all
your
when
up
use
word
how
said
an
each
she
which
do
their
time
if
will
way
about
many
then
them
would
write
like
so
these
her
long
make
thing
see
him
two
has
look
more
day
could
go
come
did
my
sound
no
most
number
who
over
know
water
than
call
first
people
may
down
side
been
now
find
any
new
work
part
take
get
place
made
live
where
after
back
little
only
round
man
year
came
show
every
good
me
give
our
under
name
very
through
just
form
much
great
think
say
help
low
line
before
turn
cause
same
mean
differ
move
right
boy
old
too
does
tell
sentence
set
three
want
air
well
also
play
small
end
put
home
read
hand
port
large
spell
add
even
land
here
must
big
high
such
follow
act
why
ask
men
change
went
light
kind
off
need
house
picture
try
us
again
animal
point
mother
world
near
build
self
earth
father
head
stand
own
page
should
country
found
answer
school
grow
study
still
learn
plant
cover
food
sun
four
thought
let
keep
eye
never
last
door
between
city
tree
cross
since
hard
start
might
story
saw
far
sea
draw
left
late
run
don't
while
press
close
night
real
life
few
stop
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched Google for "english words by frequency" and found a number of good sources. Here is one [on wiktionary.org](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.world-english.org/english500.htm)'s the top 500.  You can probably scrape out the list from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be writen this is untested but should be 99% good.

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('http://domain.tld/path/tofile.txt', 'r');
$wordList = array();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
    $wordList[] = fread($fh, 1024);
print_r($wordList);
?>
```